# Javascript to add css class on a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html is like this:

```
<table class="ListCheck">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span class="listitem">
    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$List$0" class="location" id="MainContent_List_0" type="checkbox">
    <label for="MainContent_List_0">test</label></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="listitem">
    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$List$1" class="location" id="MainContent_List_1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="MainContent_List_1">test</label></span>
</td>
<td>
<span class="listitem">
    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$List$2" class="location" id="MainContent_List_2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="MainContent_List_2">test</label></span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to add javascript to add a class on label to apply some css when the checkbox is selected

my script is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $('.listitem').each(function () {
            $(this).children("input").addClass("location");
            if ($(this).children("input").is(":checked"))
            {
                $(this).children('label').addClass("checked");
            } else {
                $(this).children('label').removeClass("checked");
            }
        });
</script>
```

But for some reason, it is not adding the class on the label at runtime. Please look at my code and let me know what I am missing. TIA.

Comment: thats jquery yo, no need to mix pure js, and what do you mean by runtime, you mean when you actually go and check something or you have things prechecked at pageload?  you'll need some event handling for the first one.

Comment: You are missing closing tags for span and input tags.Please verify it is not present in the real code

Comment: Are you calling it before the elements are even added to the page?

Comment: no, It needs to run when the checkbox is selected, add the css class to the label so that the label below the checkbox will be displayed with different fonts and colors.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to access the respective `<label>` as follows:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
     $(this).next().toggleClass("checked");
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Qd6y7/)

Comment: I need to add the css class to just the label not to the input field

Comment: @svg it's adding to the label. check the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try using your code with

```
    $( ".target" ).change(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });
```

so

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $('.listitem').each(function () {
            $(this).children("input").addClass("location");

            $(this).children("input").change(function() {

            if ($(this).children("input").is(":checked"))
            {
                $(this).children('label').addClass("checked");
            } else {
                $(this).children('label').removeClass("checked");
            }
          });// missing bracket ;)
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit, it was wrong if i understood you right.

```
   $('.location').click(function() {
                if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                {
                     console.log('added');
                    $(this).closest('label').addClass("checked");
                } else {
                    console.log('removed');
                    $(this).closest('label').removeClass("checked");
                }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W7nr4/

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code should look like this :

```
    $('.listitem').click(function () {
        $(this).children("input").addClass("location");
        if ($(this).children("input").is(":checked"))
        {
            $(this).children('label').addClass("checked");
        } else {
            $(this).children('label').removeClass("checked");
        }
    });
```

click is applied to all elements found by selector.